# Las variables Session solo funcionan en el entorno de desarrollo (JSP)

Tags: java, jsp, session

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web con *JavaServer Pages* y estoy enfrentando el siguiente problema: La pagina funciona correctamente en donde estoy desarrollando (uso NETBEANS para ello). Al momento de darle "*Run Project*`" la pagina recibe muy bien las variables de sesión.

Cuando doy "*Clean and build*" para generar el archivo `.WAR` para subirlo a mi hosting, y ejecuto la pagina desde el dominio (desde el hosting), por momentos pierdo el valor contenido en la variable de sesion, y a raiz de esto, como consecuencia salen errores (el clasico "`Java Null Pointer Exception`").

¿Cómo estoy manipulando las variables de sesion? bueno, aqui les dejo unos trozos de código:

Esto de acá es un *servlet* para iniciar sesión. Estoy guardando dos datos, el nombre del usuario y el tipo de usuario. Además de eso, le establezco un tiempo de vida (1 hora):

```
Login log = new Login();   

    log.setEmail(request.getParameter("username"));
    log.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

    try {
        if (log.iniciarSesion()) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); <---- Llamo la sesion
            session.setAttribute("username", log.getEmail()); <---- guardo usuario
            session.setAttribute("tipo", log.getTipoUser().charAt(0)); <---- guardo tipo
            MessageController.setError(false);
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600); <---- ajusto tiempo de vida (3600 segundos)
            switch (log.getTipoUser().charAt(0)) {
                case 'T':
                    response.sendRedirect("ListaObrasServlet?page=1");
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    response.sendRedirect("ListaTitularServlet?page=1");
                    break;
                default:
                    response.sendRedirect("ObrasServlet?page=1");
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            MessageController.setError(true);
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Ahora un ejemplo de como yo recupero los valores:

```
<nav class="gtco-nav" role="navigation">
                <div class="gtco-container">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div id="gtco-logo"><a href="index.jsp">VUDA </a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 text-right menu-1">
                            <ul> 
                                <% if(session.getAttribute("tipo").toString().contains("U")){ %>
                                    ETC ETC ETC ETC
                                     <% }else if(session.getAttribute("tipo").toString().contains("T")){%>
                                    ETC ETC ETC ETC
                                <% }else if(session.getAttribute("tipo").toString().contains("S")){ %>
                                    ETC ETC ETC ETC
                                <%}%>
                                (mas y mas html)
                                <% if(session.getAttribute("tipo").toString().contains("U") ){%>
                                    ETC ETC ETC ETC
                                <% } %>
                                <li><a href="#">Contactenos</a></li>
                                  <li  class="btn-cta" <% if(session.getAttribute("username")!=null ) out.print("style='display:none;'");%>><a id="btn2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><span>Usuario</span></a></li>
                                <li  class="btn-cta" <% if(session.getAttribute("username")!=null ) out.print("style='display:inline;'");else out.print("style='display:none;'");%>><a href="logoutServlet"><span>Cerrar Sesion</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </nav>
```

Pues como les comentaba, repito el problema: **todo funciona bien cuando ejecuto desde el netbeans**, pero cuando subo la página al hosting, **pierdo el valor contenido en la sesion al cambiar de página**. Hay momentos que funciona todo bien, pero de la nada ocurre eso.

*Nota:* En el archivo XML tambien tengo puesto el tiempo de vida de las sesiones con esto:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        60
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

¿Que podria ser?

**ACTUALIZACION:** Descubrí que la sesión en realidad muere apenas cambias de página en el hosting, y no me explico porque (El servidor es un Ubuntu Server). Que se supone que hace el Netbeans para mantenerlas vivas?

Ya estoy seguro que es temas de configuracion. En el servidor para poder mantener las sessiones vivas en cada página, tengo que utilizar `encodeURL` ... pero esto se me hace demasiado molesto. Como hago para que el servidor *GlassFish* mantenga la session viva? Lo que utilizo en mi Stack Web es:

- *Sistema Operativo: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS*
- *Web Server: GlassFish Server 4.1.1*
- *Base de datos: MySQL*
- *Lenguaje de programacion: Java Server Pages*

Comment: ¿Cuando despliegas usando NetBeans también usas la misma versión de GlassFish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Tienes varios WAR's en el servidor de aplicaciones?

Yo he tenido problemas en un Websphere teniendo varias aplicaciones por culpa de la cookie de sesión (JSESSIONID), ya que todas utilizaban el mismo nombre.

A mi me funcionó cambiarle el nombre de la cookie de sesión a algunas aplicaciones de manera que el nombre fuera único y no se pudiera repetir.

Quizás podrías probarlo en Glashfish a ver si funciona

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beash.html

Comment: Me has salvado la vida. Mil gracias por tu sugerencia

Answer (score 1):

espero ayudarte con esta breve idea que tengo.

Yo creo que pierdes las variables de sesión por el número de veces que haces las peticiones. Tengo entendido que con `sendRedirect()` realizas una nueva petición y esto es muy usado cuando se tratan de peticiones POST y los atributos no sean visibles, pero cuando reenvías no haces una nueva petición sino que, la misma petición va a ir viajando por cada uno de los servlets que tú le indiques y manteniendo siempre la misma URL en el navegador y se realiza con:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("ruta del jsp que quieres ir").forward(request, response);
```

Con eso siempre se va a mantener la misma sesión o hasta que tú la elimines.

Espero haber ayudado en algo.